# How to set base href dynamically based on url path in angular 15

Tags: angular, frontend, angular-ui-router

As per the requirement, i want to use two different urls for the same angular 15 application.
For example:
URL 1 : https://ex.com/users
URL 2 : https:// ex.com/guest/users
Both above url should load same application. But the issue is, chunk files are always generated in the root path only. So it throwing 404 error when we call url 2.
How to change path for chunk files ie.main.js, poyfill.js etc.

I have tried using base-href, but it dint work. All chunk files are generated in the baseHref mentioned path in angular.json file. but i m expecting as below

Eg: for URL1, all chunk files should get in the below path
http://ex.com/users/main.js
http://ex.com/users/polyfill.js

for URL2: it should be in below path
http://ex.com/guest/users/main.js
http://ex.com/guest/users/polyfill.js

How to achieve this? Can someone help me on this issue ?

Comment: If you're loading the same app from two paths, an Angular solution might be overkill. Have you considered doing something like an .htaccess redirect?